# Link-Only Attitude of Low Quality Posts vs say First Post Queues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I am writing this as a slight twist to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers/251007#251007).  The issue there has to do with why people get penalized for flagging link-only answers when the faqs say we should flag such posts.  That is: Why are flags rejected in this case?

My question is how come there is a radio button for link-only answers as a reason for low quality posts, but it takes so long when one flags a first post queue item for link-only and then it often gets rejected?  Is there justification to have two sets of attitudes towards link-only answers?  Is this perception, or are there two different rationales in play here?

To go further, I would like to point out that some of the review audits for the low quality queue are: Can you spot the link only answer and flag it?  If you don't flag them, you will get you review privileges taken away.

Comment: I just took another look at the flagging dialog, and I don't see the radio button for link only answers that you describe in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It is the bottom one for me if memory serves me right.  I cannot do a screenshot for now because I have exhausted my 20 for the day.

Comment: Your memory serves right. There is a link-only radio button in the low-quality queue which is where posts end up from late answer and first posts. Robert may have confused it with those.

Answer (score 7):

First, not every answer that has a link in it needs to be deleted. From looking at your recent flagging history, the ones I see being rejected are ones where there was indeed more to the answer than just a link. All of the ones on answers that are nothing more than "read this tutorial for the answer", which [we have been instructed to remove](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) were accepted and the answer removed.

To your point, though, there isn't so much a difference in review queue as there is a difference in how you flag. If you use a custom flag that states "link-only answer", those are only reviewed by moderators. If you instead use a standard "very low quality" or "not an answer" flag, most of those are now handled by the community via the Low Quality Posts review queue.

There may be slight differences in how things are handled between the two sets of reviewers. I think it's safe to say that moderators will probably be a little more careful in our reviews than some reviewers, which might lead to a little variance there. Also, one moderator may have a different opinion than others would on a borderline post. Personally, I tend to be less likely to delete things than others, as one example.

In reality, as has been stated many times before, there isn't such a thing as a standard "link-only answer". There are answers that lean heavily on links, but there's a lot of grey area there. Each one of these needs to be examined on its own merits, and that will lead to differences in how these are handled.

Comment: `First, not every answer that has a link in it needs to be deleted.` -> Disagree, so does the majority of [the community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).