# Answer with only link without actual code (answer depends on external library)

Tags: discussion

Is it right to consider the answer link-only and flag it in the case when:

The answer depends (for example) on external js library and it points to it's webpage and documentation. I understand that we need to include code because the website can simply become obsolete (inaccessible), but in that scenario the answer will become obsolete either as it simply depends on external library and if library is inaccessible (obsolete) the code example is obsolete either.

Comment: Hrm, first hit in Related section, [Flagging link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251006/464709)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, I saw it before posting my question, but I don't see the answer to my question and example there. If it is there and you point me I would be very grateful. Until that I don't see reason to close my question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have edited the title to make my answer more specific and point that it is not actually duplicate and I can't see answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of spam, you can mostly ignore links when evaluating answers for this purpose. Either the answer tries to answer the question, or it doesn't.

- If the answer to the question could plausibly be "Use External JS Library™", so be it.
- If it clearly can't be, then that's not an answer.
- Rarely if ever is the answer to any question "use this it will help you".
- Etc.

See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)