# Are answers with only links to libraries okay?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

### Preface

This question is here to serve one of two purposes, and the community will decide which one it is:

1. Correct how I am reviewing answers in the Low Quality Post review queue if my current understanding of a low-quality answer is incorrect.
2. Help draw attention to a common misuse of the Not-an-Answer flag if my understanding is correct.

### The Situation

We all want to discourage posting link-only answers that point to code examples and say nothing more than, "look here." It has been [well established](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/273585) that in the Stack Overflow community, we don't want them. However, I don't believe there is anything wrong with an answer that says, "what you're trying to do has already been done; consider using library XYZ", and providing a link to the library.The answers would be *better* with a small code snippet to demonstrate the usage of the library, but I don't think the answer is entirely useless without it.

A few notes to consider:

- Library links are susceptible to link-rot like any other links, but as long as the answerer gives the name of the library, future visitors can likely still find it somewhere even if the link is dead.
- We seem to be okay with answers that have library links *and* some example code, but if the library is completely unavailable, then an answer without the example code just as useless, so I consider them to be equally undeserving of a Not-an-Answer flag.
- A lot of the link-to-library answers that I've reviewed have gone on to be deleted, suggesting that my current interpretation is incorrect.
- On the other hand, the first bullet-point given by Shog9 in [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262385/2615940) suggests that my interpretation is correct.

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377634/2615940

### The Question

Are answers that only contain a link to an external library acceptable?

In other words, am I correct to mark those kinds of answers as "Looks Okay" in the review queue and users should stop flagging them, or should I be marking them for deletion?

### Last Note

Spam is outside the scope of this question. I agree that spam should always be flagged.

Comment: also related: [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Link only answers are not acceptable. The test is that if you take the link away is the answer still an answer?

Answers should stand on their own and be a complete answer to the question being asked. You mention link rot, but more importantly we shouldn't be directing people somewhere else for their answer.

If the answer **is** a link to a library then that's a really good indication that the question should closed as library recommendation.

The correct procedure is to do one or more of the following:

- Leave a comment asking the poster to expand their answer.
- Down-vote the answer.
- Edit the relevant information into the answer.
- Vote to delete (if you have enough reputation and the answer is already negatively scoring).

You shouldn't need to involve the moderators in this process.

However in this case is appears that I misread the answer when deleting it (and I'm sorry that it's taken this long for me to realise that). The problem is that the answer *looks* like a link only answer.

Comment: Does closing the question as off-topic also take care of the answer?  Or only future ones?

Comment: @ryanyuyu It only prevents future answers being posted. Existing answers need to be dealt with by down-voting then deleting.

Comment: I disagree that if a library is an answer then it means the question must be requesting a library. If I post a question asking for help debugging code that removes a node from a graph, and someone suggests that I save myself the trouble and use a graph library instead, it doesn't necessarily mean that I asked for a library.

Comment: @skrrgwasme - I said it was a good indication, not that it was always the case.

Comment: @skrrgwasme In that case, should it really be an answer? I'd see it more as a comment (ie: "Why do you break your head? this library does it : ")

Comment: @Patrice That's a very good point. I especially like the way you phrased "break your head."

Comment: I don't agree at all with your interpretation of "link-only". If the link in [the answer you deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29377634/1709587) were to die, it would still tell me to use the `i2c_read_device` function of the PIGPIO library. I don't know enough about the domain to know if that's good advice or not, but the answer plainly has content even with the link removed. I don't think it should've been deleted. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288055/1709587 where Boltclock and Shog disagree with you; the mod team clearly does not have one mind on this issue. I'm on their side.

Comment: @Mark - I don't see any difference between what Boltclock and Shog are saying in the answer you link to and what I'm saying here. We are both saying that an answer must be able to stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @ChrisF You cite the "no link-only answers; answers must stand on their own" rule to justify the deletion of answers that do nothing more than name and link to a library that solves the asker's problem. (In fact, the answer you deleted even went further and named the function to use!) Shog uses the same rule to argue that answers that name and link to libraries that solve the asker's problem are strictly permissible and should not be deleted. Same rule, same explanation of its meaning, but polar opposite interpretations as applied to "library-only" answers.

Comment: @MarkAmery - I was on mobile this morning so I wasn't able to double check the answer being referenced. I have undeleted it for now, but it still need improvement to add more explanation.

Comment: This contradicts the answer at the linked dupe which says link only answer are acceptable if the link is the answer. Apparently if I ask "how do I split a string in Javascript" an acceptable answer is just a link to the docs of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), at least according to the answer on the dupe.

Comment: @gman Are you sure that they didn't mean a question like "where's the official documentation to xxx" where the link is the only answer? It seems that "how do I split.." does have answers that are not just links.

Comment: I'm just passing on what I read. I mostly feel links only answer should be deleted 100% of the time but I've tried to get answers deleted with only links and they are not deleted. Even official docs can be moved or go offline.