# Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

Let me illustrate this with a very simple example. The user asks about how to make a simple, cross-browser AJAX request.

I answer the question with some explanation, `sample code`, and links to resources, should the user wish to read and learn more about the technologies and practices at his/her further disposal.

Is it acceptable in this situation to recommend my say, lightweight AJAX library, with a link to its homepage? Again, as part of a detailed, *well thought-out* answer.

The reason for promoting this example library is not to obtain revenue or visitors, but to express a biased opinion, stating the usefulness of said example library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/248731

Comment: Sure, as long you keep your answers in context, and don't just promote a link as _that's your solution_. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1413395+sttcl) for example.

Comment: Mentions here and there should happen organically, as you naturally bump into questions which might benefit from your lib. Don't go hunting out questions just so you can create answers that use your lib. That is not a good thing and leads to great sadness.

Comment: Instead of saying "here's how to do it with my library", try "here's how my library implements this".  Then readers can choose between using your library or implementing something customized for their particular situation, making your answer more useful overall.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: If someone bothered writing a library for the task, odds are good that "here's how my library implements this" is going to be woefully simplistic or too voluminous to make a good answer.

Comment: @EthanFurman I was thinking of questions that can be answered using one feature of a library. If someone wrote a (nontrivial) library _solely_ for that task, the question may be (but isn't always) too broad. Either way, I agree the answerer needs to be judicious in their level of detail -- "just do X" and a line-by-line commentary are both bad, but there's a middle ground that explains the concepts in enough detail for someone considering rolling their own solution to at least get started from, and often helps those who choose to use the library as-is do so properly.

Comment: One thing people always forget about adding their own software which genuinely helps and answers the question is adding that the software is from them. You need to give yourself a pat on the back (many don't want to but you really should) and make sure you state you made the software but how it can really help. If you do not give proper attribution it could be seen as spam.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> *"Again, as part of a detailed, well thought-out answer."*

In that case it's absolutely OK, to additionally promote your own (open source required IMHO) library packaged solution.

The point is not just linking to it, but make a concise explanation, why using this would be better, than creating a solution from scratch.

Comment: _"why using this would be better, than creating a solution from scratch"_ - yes, that's exactly what I meant, thank you.

Comment: It's important to add that quantity is relevant. Posting once or twice when you happen across questions where it fits is fine; searching through the archive and posting to dozens of questions in a short time span is not OK.

Comment: Also you want to add a disclaimer that you are the author of the library.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I dunno about that. If the end result in each case is still a good, valuable, non-spammy answer then who cares how he found the question or how often he did so? More valuable answers should be a good thing, no? So what if his intent deep down is a bit of promotion: the result is not harming anybody. We're all in this for various self-serving reasons, anyway; the rep, the fame, the whatever... Who cares? I'd say take each answer as its own case and forget the wider picture. (tl;dr: quantity _isn't_ relevant, really)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ratio of total questions to questions which have links in them is, however.

Comment: @Amelia: Why?​​

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because when that gets too high it results in a moderator contacting the user and warning them for what's akin to product placement. It's subjective, though.

Comment: @Amelia: Why is it "product placement" if the answers are valuable in their own right, as discussed above?

Comment: If the question already has a high quality answer, adding another answer with a link can only ever *add* the link - this should probably become a comment on the existing high quality answer.  If the question does not have a high quality answer, we shouldn't discourage posting a new answer regardless of the motivations.  In all cases, the connection of the author to the library should be made evident.

Answer (score 15):

I have seen that more than once actually. What I've usually noticed is

1. a *disclaimer* given at the top or the bottom of the post.
2. In the post **the question is answered** (that is important), and the library/plug-in/service is given as an example. or supplements the explanation.

If both elements exist I think it's fine.

Answer (score 8):

I think there's two important things to note here,

1. If something provides a good answer to the question which will help others in the future, it should be allowed and encouraged (I would even go so far as to say to spite the motives of the answerer).
2. If the *question* is asking for a library recommendation its off topic anyway, so you should be closing it not answering it.

That being said your answer must:

- Answer the question inline, any link must be supplementary info.
- Register you are the author of the offsite resource (eg **Disclaimer:** I wrote this library)

Comment: A simple and unobtrusive "my" is enough, no need to put up a billboard.

Comment: @Deduplicator anything is fine i think

Comment: Would you consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317186/recommendations-for-lightweight-open-source-ajax-library-in-javascript off topic? Or is it one of the cases where - sticking to the example - "promoting" that said library would be welcome? I mean, it is seen as helpful by some folks.

Comment: @JánosWeisz Yes this is off topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @JánosWeisz In the case of the question you refer to there is not going to be a 'right' answer, which means that people can only post an opinionated answer such as *I like this library*. This is a pretty old question (I think) predating this help page and close reason which is probably why It hasn't been closed.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think 'promote' is the right word to use. If you have made a library (preferably open source as others mentioned) that is applicable to the question and the answer you are giving then by all means it should be included. There's no one better than yourself to explain how to use it to solve a problem.

However, keep in mind that the goal here is to answer the person's question and lead them to a solution. You're not *promoting* anything. Don't fill your answer with off topic comments about why your library is better than others, or the hard work that went into making your library and so on. Stick to answering the question at hand, and not trying to bring attention to your personal achievement.