# Linking to my own repository in the answers

Tags: discussion, external-links

I have a question about linking to my repository in my answers.

Here's a situation. I'm top 2 answerer in the `Laravel` tag and top 1 in terms of number of answers. I'm saying this to show that I care about helping people and that was the main reason to create the repo I'll be talking about.

I see that the most of Laravel developers are struggling because of the absence of any source for the best practices for Laravel apps like comminity conventions, putting JS into PHP templates etc. So I've decided to [create one](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) a few months ago.

Now, [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367475/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-docgenerator-curricul) in my answers I'm giving a link to the repository. But a moderator changed all those links by adding a disclaimer to my answers that the repo belongs to me and asked me to do the same.

But the problem is I'm feeling like a cheap door to door salesman who sells crap when I'm adding a link with a disclaimer like that. I would be happy to place a link to another source of Laravel best practices, but there is no such source ([this one](http://www.laravelbestpractices.com/) is framework agnostic, nothing about Laravel there. Even their disclaimer says about that).

Of course, I want to popularize the repo, but I definitely do not want to sell it like a tricky salesman.

Also, I'm not hiding the fact I'm the owner because my nickname of SO and in the repo is the same (which is my real name).

So, my question is: is it possible to **not** add [this ugly disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367510/1227923) to every link in this circumstances? I mean when there is only one source for this kind of information and adding these disclaimers just because the source if yours is awful in my opinion. I'd rather to not put these links at all even it will be super helpful for a new Laravel guy.

Or maybe there is a way to tell people it's my repo without a disclaimer? For example, is it ok if the link would be a simple HTTP link where everybody can see my name without even clicking it:

https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices

**Update**

The most of the guys missed the point of the question. The thing is this repo is the **only** source for the info and it was created to help SO users. So, I literally can't post a link to any other source.

Before this, I had no problems because of posting the link to the repo except downvotes from that one guy. And like 10 random guys said me in the comments the repo is great, so people like the repo itself.

But now, when I'm using phrases like "Learn more about Laravel naming conventions in my best practices repo", my answers get downvotes. So, I think now people think I'm just trying to sell my repo.

Comment: See [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085). and https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion. **Not** disclosing this is your own project makes you look like the cheap door to door salesman.

Comment: And all you have to do is use words like 'this project I created' or 'my repository', that's really about it. The moderator stated this already.

Comment: So, the fact the source is unique means literally nothing? I mean I can't put the link to any another source, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Removing the 'disclaimer ' and 'following SO rules I must say' would already make your disclaimer less ugly, imho.

Comment: Something like `For more information about naming conventions, see [this article](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) on my best practices site.` would suffice. As long as it's *supporting*, rather than *providing*, the answer and you're explicit about your relationship with the material, that's fine. You don't have to actually use the word *"disclaimer"* or use special formatting or anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, that sounds really good.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: people will only flag you for not stating it is your project while it obviously is yours judging from the name. And I fail to see why it is so onerous to just use 'my' in a sentence?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess because moderator added something like  `Disclaimer: this repository belongs to me` I thought it should look like that. But John's disclaimer looks great and I've already changed the link title in the answer and going to use it in the future if it's really not against the rules.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: If you read the second message the moderator sent you, you'll see they used similar wording there too.

Comment: Closely related, possibly even a duplicate: [What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361284)

Comment: Yeah, that's the guy (OP in the linked question) who started all this editing stuff. He edited my first answer, downvoted and called a moderator who edited all other answers with links to the repo. You can close the question or mark it as a duplicate, I don't mind. My problem is solved now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can post the answer if you want, so I could accept it.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I only began to flag when it became apparent you didn't want to (initially) follow the rules, as you edit warred with me and began to downvote unrelated posts of mine.  I only downvoted because of the rule breaking; once the offending material was rectified, I removed the downvote.  Your initial(and subsequent) response(s), blasting me for telling you why, is just another reason why no one likes to explain their downvote(s).

Comment: see also: [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298734/839601)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I checked the last 5 days of your reputation history, and can see no downvotes that match the assertion you make in the edit to your question; can you please specify posts where you see this occurring?  I should clarify; the downvotes I refer to in the prior sentence are not my own; they are -2s in your rep history to signify a downvote.  The only thing I can see this question may be based on is going to be in a subsequent comment as I am running out of room here;

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418613/using-name-column-in-belongstomany-relation-instead-of-id/48418653#comment83884456_48418653) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48418653/785241) is the only evidence I can find of what you're talking about, and even then, the content of the comment does not support your assertion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I link back to other answers of mine all the time. Each time I do, I do my best to refer to them as "my answer to this question" or something similar where appropriate. When I start publishing more content on my blog, I plan to link back to it similarly by referring to "my blog post". All for the purpose of *supporting* content within my answers themselves, of course, as you do.

You certainly don't need an ugly disclaimer; you just need to make it clear that the guidelines you link to are your own ideas. I agree that jonrsharpe's example is pretty good:

> For more information about naming conventions, see [this article](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-pract%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bices#follow-laravel-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnaming-conventions) on my best practices site.

It doesn't read like boilerplate, legalese, or "I made this library-that-clearly-isn't" or anything like that. It reads like an organic part of your answer, with relevant keywords and context.

As to whether having an awkward disclaimer or none at all is better, well, the rules suggest that we'd much rather see an awkward disclaimer, as long as there *is* one. Having said that, I personally wasn't a fan of how awkward the ones that were edited in sounded either, so I don't particularly blame you for choosing to withdraw the links to your work altogether instead for the sake of complying with the rules.

But hopefully things have been cleared up now and you have a better idea of how to share your guidelines while disclosing your authorship thereof going forward.