# Why does Stack Overflow keep deleting stuff I post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, self-promotion

I had a huge problem to exchange encrypted messages between C# and JS and from what I read on Stack Overflow and other help pages (Microsoft, etc), a lot of other people seem to have the same problem.

So I worked on a small library on Github under the MIT license which solves the problem completely - in contrast to the many insufficient answers on Stack Overflow, etc. However, when I posted my solution on Stack Overflow yesterday, it got deleted by a moderator.

It is completely unclear to me why it was deleted. I cannot contact the moderator through their Stack Overflow page (at least I don't see any Contact or PM button).

What's going on here?

Comment: 1. Questions *about* SO should go on [meta]. 2. [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) are not considered useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll also add that answers that endorse a library or product without disclosing the author's affiliation are considered spam. I don't know what was the content of the question that was deleted but even if it wasn't link-only, it might have been deleted because as spam.

Comment: @VLAZ based on the two as-yet-undeleted answers I can see promoting the library, they do at least say they're the author

Comment: You can add some code on how to use the library and that will handy.

Comment: The fact that your username sounds like a company and the phrasing of this question is a bit self-possessed, you may be coming off poorly.  SO tends to value a sense of human connection and humility.

Answer (score 4):

Promoting your library to solve a problem is acceptable on SO but only under certain conditions, otherwise it will *likely* be treated as spam. Those conditions are:

1. Always include that the library is yours.
2. Specify with some code about the workings of the library.
3. Specify why to use a library to solve this problem.
4. Explain why using your library will be better than any other approach.
5. Include steps for using your library.

Also, see [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer).

If you really want to solve a problem then you have to mention your approach and how you tackle it. Just a link to your library is not  sufficient - [it will be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Generally, solutions to problems that require a whole library to solve are not considered ideal solutions. A suggestion: You could make an optimized code snippet which addresses the problem at hand,  ask a question about it, then post your snippet while mentioning what you did and why you did it.

[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, I am totally irritated about this. I acted in good faith.
While working on a project I encountered 2 really extremely tough obstacles:
1. Convert from DOCX to PDF or from HTML to PDF programmatically with C#
2. Encrypting/decrypting between C# and JS.

In both problems, I only found hints for a solution either on Stackoverflow. Thus, I made 2 sep. libraries, which solve them AND are easy-to-use under MIT-license (open source, free, etc) to solve other's headaches. But both of my posts were deleted over and over again.Stackoverflow is difficult to contribu

Comment: @SmartInMedia Curation is not done based on invisible intent, it is done based on what questions and answers contain. So show your intent in the answers and it should be fine. If you want to do something about your irritation, you have all the opportunity.