# Link-Only answer awarded bounty

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty, low-quality-posts, accepted-answer

I found an answer:

> One of noUiSlider's core features is the ability to divide the range in a non-linear fashion. Stepping can be applied, too! The example on the right shows where the handles are on the slider range in values and percentages. [NoUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-non-linear)

which is copy paste from the link, Link-Only and contains no any working code as well as explanation, but it has claimed to provide solution to the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113180/implement-jquery-slider-on-uncertain-timeline) on an external link. Interesting thing is, it has been awarded a bounty and on the comment section, we can see author commenting:

> Thanks a lot man!! you are very late because I have already started working on creating custom slider. Anyways You deserves to get bounty. :)

**What can we do in this condition?**

**Is it ok to post an answer to that question which author no longer needs answer for?**

**Do I need to raise a flag against the answer?**

Post Link: [Implement jQuery slider on uncertain timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113180/implement-jquery-slider-on-uncertain-timeline)

Comment: The question doesn't rule out answers offering an plugin and there is not much else to offer as a link because you're not going to copy the source code into the answer. If they bring an example that is about it. I don't think that answer is flagable.

Comment: Will this be a valid answer when the link becomes inacessible? A nice discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289074/are-answers-with-only-links-to-libraries-okay

And how about copy pasted example?

Comment: You can DV the answer.  Or edit it to make it better.  The normal Q+A sensibilities just no longer apply when a question can't get answered in two days.  A bounty rarely produces useful Q+A.  Just A's, that's its intention.

Comment: @rene won't it be counted as defacing the original content when we edit an accepted answer with our own code?

Comment: The answer is an answer without the link: it mentions the library noUIslider has those features. That the link will rot is not an direct issue. It is not a great answer so the advice given by Hans is far out the best. And provide an answer that only has dependency on VanillaJS.

Comment: @KiranShakya post a new answer, at best without using the library. The answer is even plagiarized.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have posted my own answer this time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113180/implement-jquery-slider-on-uncertain-timeline/42317210#answer-42317210