# Why was this answer low quality?

Tags: discussion, support

Today, I was reviewing *First Posts* and came across an answer to review.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15402095
Answer from "Ruslan Shashkov"

[image]

This answer is now deleted due to low quality.

Ruslan has developed a library that may help solving the issue raised by the OP. The OP has already accepted the OTHER answer, so this may help others in future.

> Links may die in future

True and this is a valid reason for considering something a poor post; all links including the links to answers on Stack Overflow may die in the future. The link he posted belongs to GitHub. That site is equally reliable as Stack Overflow.

> Reason for deletion was "no relevant information related to link".

What relevant information may be added here? It's a library; a lot of code. Relevant code may be too large to post in an answer. The description to solve the problem may also be too large **through the way implemented in library**.

Note that this is a **library**, NOT an **article**. Also note that this library is NOT well known; so Ruslan has no way but to post a link. Otherwise, he could have simply commented with the name of library.

> Post it as comment instead of answer

In my understanding, this is a valid reason for that answer being low quality. He has enough reputation to comment.

But this may not be true for other new users.

> Asking for ready made software library is off topic

Agree, but this is an **answer**, NOT a question. Ruslan thought his library may solve the problem raised by the OP. So he posted link to it.

This answer looks good to me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: IMO if the answerer had added a some code or explanation of how it solves the problem from the link, it wouldn't be low quality. Even Github projects tend to get moved on occasion.

Comment: Relevent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar: That link belongs to **article**. This link belongs to **library**.

Comment: SO is not a s/w recommendation site if a user wants a ready to use library for his problem he can try any s/w recommendation site on internet.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar: The post is **Answer**; not a question. The one who answered thinks that the issue raised by OP may be solved by the library he developed. So he posted it as answer.

Comment: A link to a library isn't an answer. It's a link to something that might be able to be used to provide an answer. But it's not an answer to the question (unless the question is "find me a library", which we've already established is off topic)

Comment: Link to a library, Is OK. But demonstrate how it solve the issue of OP. When asking for  Relevant code . We are not asking for a line by line explanation on how the core of the library work. But the 4 line you need to intanciate. And the 4 line you need to solve the problem using the library.. If it's just a link, is not an answer.

Comment: see also: [Are answers with only links to libraries okay?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289074/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Low Quality for two reasons:

- It depends entirely on the link.
- The answerer promotes their own work.

The first part has already been discussed in the comments: GitHub projects can move or change. If the link changes, or if the project changes, the link is no longer valid - and we have no history of the change inside Stack Overflow.

**The answer should explain how it was solved in this library, so we can recreate it for ourselves.**

Second, it's the answerer's own project. The answerer may be answering in good faith, but we can't tell for sure. There's no lack of people who try to use SO to spamvertize their own work, so we need to be careful there.

If the answerer would explain how it was solved in their library, then they could leave the link for reference. But the answer should not rely on the link.

All we really need in the answer is the guidelines on *how* to solve it. 
Supporting that with a link to an implementation is great, *if* it is done to help the OP and future visitors. It should never be  an excuse to spamvertize one's own work. (Not saying the answerer was; I'm assuming good faith on the answerer's part).

If the question requires an entire GitHub project to be answered properly, then the question itself is Too Broad, and should be closed as such.