# Should the posts posting links to own sites be treated as spam?

Tags: discussion, triage, spam, external-links, self-promotion

Following post was presented to me for triage review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/17379239

[image]

It contains link to website apparently owned/developed by OP.

This does not look obvious spam to me. OP is attempting to ask genuine question. The only thing that concerns is the link to his own product.

I remember [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344847/5779732) answer for one of my questions on meta which says:

> The answerer promotes their own work.
>   it's the answerer's own project. The answerer may be answering in good faith, but we can't tell for sure. There's no lack of people who try to use SO to spamvertize their own work, so we need to be careful there.

Should this kind of post be treated and flagged as spam? If no, what is the best way to treat this kind of posts?

Comment: Lacks MCVE is a good choice.

Comment: @NathanOliver: What about spam? Should this NOT be treated as spam?

Comment: have a look at [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) which is actually in the triage link you looked at

Comment: @AmitJoshi To me it is borderline.  It loks like an honest attempt to ask a question so I'm giving them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I just found this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497. It looks not every self-promotion link is spam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question has a lot of problems, but I wouldn't flag it as spam. It looks like they included the link only as a reference to the site they're asking a question about, not as an attempt to drive traffic. I'm voting to close that question for the following reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

I'd only start to treat questions like this as spam if a user shows a pattern of linking to their site in several questions. Right now they only have two (one from last year). It looks like they haven't gotten the message yet that they need to include code in their questions, but I don't think it's reached the spam level yet.

**Note:** I can't see the site they linked to because my firewall blocks it. If they link to a NSFW site or a site that's clearly trying to advertise to us, I'd be a lot quicker to throw a spam flag.

Comment: Can you please explain "if a user shows a pattern of linking to their site in several questions" this in more details? The question was presented to me while review. Just to make sure the pattern is not repeated, should I visit his all questions and read those? Does not look practically possible.

Comment: @AmitJoshi There are links to the question and the user's profile in the review. If you're not sure, you can follow those links to get more information.

Comment: It is an apparel shopping website Bill.

Comment: I can see the site and it is clearly an advertise. But on other hand, as I said in question, OP is attempting to ask genuine question. The only thing that concerns is the link to his own product.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I think it's borderline at this point. Since they do seem to be *trying* to ask a question, I'd give them the benefit of the doubt this time. The more they link to their site, though, the more inclined I'll be to treat it as spam.