# How should I know why this specific answer is spam?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam, specific-answer

In Low Quality Posts Review, I was presented with following audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17533710

I read the answer and choose Looks Ok. I failed this audit.

[image]

The link in answer is to youtube video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E8Yh4dw6Diw

Following is the question to which the answer was posted:

> I am trying to return pointer from a function. But I am getting segmentation fault. Someone please tell what is wrong with the code
>
> `Some c code posted by OP to explain the problem.`

I know near to nothing about C language; just a general understanding.

Question is asking for some help about working of pointers in his code. Answerer is answering the same. The youtube video is good and explains the same.

So, what exactly is wrong with this answer?

The thing that most confuses me is that, the banner at top says:

> It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

I do not understand how the answer is abusive or noise or spam etc?

This may be wrong answer (I am not sure if it is), but AFAIK wrong answer should not be the reason for flagging. Those should be down-voted instead. Down-vote button is not available in this review.

I visited the profile page of user.

- User have zero posts (both questions and answers) or may be his posts are deleted.
- Users profile page does not contain the youtube (and any other) link.
- User name on Stack Overflow is not a real name; I cannot verify on youtube that the video belongs to user and the action is for self promotion.

That said, I have no way to learn if the user is repeatedly posting the link for self promotion.

If my reviewing capabilities are being tested by audit, those must be tested **within the scope** I can review. Moderators or high reputation users may spot this as spam because more data/tools/privileges are available to them. This is not available to me. In this case, the audit should not be presented to me at all because I do not have enough tools to PASS it.

User profile page will only show me that there are no answers. That means, answer presented to me is audit and is already deleted by moderator. I am fine up to this. Now next, what action should I take on audit? "Looks Ok" is correct action in my view looking **only at the answer presented to me** in review. But that is already deleted; so "Looks Ok" is out of choice. "Edit" is not a choice. I will be happy to "Skip" but it does not make sense to skip **just because moderator deleted it**. I do not think I will **PASS** the audit if I skip it. Only way to pass the audit is to "Recommend Delete". With the data/tools/privileges available to me, I do not see the good reason to delete this post.

With the resources available to me, how can I judge accurately that this answer is spam?

**Note:**

- I am not complaining about why my audit is failed.
- This [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356754/5779732) explains Spam Flag is not appropriate just because OP post a link to his own resource. It should be treated spam only if the pattern is repeated. As I said above, I have no way to check the pattern.

Comment: Probably a user who kept posting links to their own site and/or YouTube channel. That may have caused the answer to be deleted as spam.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: There are two problems in that case: 1) Answer is NOT link only answer. Even though user is posting the link to his own video repeatedly, link is additional info. Answer explains what the problem may be. 2) How should I make sure while reviewing each post that the user has not posted the link in other answers as well? This is near to impossible for any reviewer.

Comment: But wouldn't the user be banned if they were caught posting spam?

Comment: New answers to a 6 year old question that just about everybody knows the answer to in general need to be, erm, impressive.  That wasn't.   Audits test if the reviewer is paying attention.  Not seeing that the post was deleted is a good way to fail one.  That question is attracting a lot of useless late answers, protected.

Comment: @HansPassant: Even though it is new answer to old question, what is wrong with the answer itself? This is common on Stack Overflow. Why it is abusive or spam? Will you please explain bit more?

Comment: For context, it is a well-documented problem that the audits themselves are poor quality. See many similar questions in the past where the answer is often "that wasn't actually a very easy one to pass, let's remove it", and/or "it's fine to skip if you are not familiar with that particular tag, actually".

Comment: @AmitJoshi It's not a link-only answer, but it does smell like self-promotion. So check if it is. Is the link also present in the user's profile page? Do they have other answers linking to the same site? If new users do this, I often leave a comment warning them that overt self-promotion is not allowed.

Comment: That said, if the user's other answers are deleted, it _is_ indeed difficult to check for patterns of self-promotion. When checking the user's other recent answers, you would find that this one was deleted too. For completeness: if it is not an audit, and you spot a pattern of self-promotion... then a custom mod flag is the right action. With links to recent self-promoting answers as evidence.

Comment: The vast majority of programmers would just leave the Q+A alone, given that it is adequately answered and too trivial to need more posts.  Some programmers cannot resist however, especially so when, say, they created a YouTube video.  Flaggers correctly identified the post as project spam and a mod deleted it.  Not identifying posts as spam when you review and ignoring the advice from SO users that there is an issue with a post is, well, rather a problem.  If you have no idea whatsoever why SO users would flag a post then the Skip button is always the best choice.

Comment: The standard mistakes reviewers appear to make is to start with the assumption that SO users flag posts for no good reason and to not look at the Q+A but rely on the myopic view presented by the review page.  Given that you have no real idea why SO users flagged the post, you only have two real options to progress.  You either click Skip or you have to take a look to learn more.  At which point you instantly know a lot more, you for one can never fail the audit.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: The question is very old and user profile page have no questions and answers. This means the answer presented to me for review is already deleted. Ok. My question is "Why the answer should be deleted?", If this is spam, then why this is spam? Old posts are not visible to me. If I am reviewing a post, I should have the tools to verify these things. May be, moderator can see the deleted questions, I cannot.

Comment: "No tools available" is weird.  Just having a look doesn't require any tools.  The third most common mistake btw, after a while reviewers start robo-clicking.  It is galley slave duty, I wish the company would do a better job at it and present review as a finite job with, say, no more than 10 reviews at a time.  A task to waste away 15 minutes. Preferable with a set of posts that are a good match with the reviewer's profile.  That would help keeping reviewers interested in the task, the fourth most common problem is that people quit and nobody learns how to do it right.

Comment: If you go to a user's profile page and see that they have no posts... bingo! That means the post you're reviewing was already deleted. In that case, you don't need 10K tools to see if there was a pattern, it's clear that it's an audit.

Comment: This was an answer I deleted, and I agree that it was not a fair audit. This answer was flagged as spam on the day it was posted. My criteria for upholding the spam flag were pretty borderline, but I decided that since it was posted by a 1 rep user, and posted to a question from 2011 that had an accepted answer that it was probably only posted to drive traffic to that YouTube video.

Comment: @AmitJoshi This question is closed, no new answers can be posted, and I don't really have any further detail to provide.

Comment: By the way, **practically** it is very hard for any reviewer to visit users profile page and read all other posts if the post contains link to external resource. If Stack Overflow is proposing to do this, it should come up with some good and reviewer friendly tool for this. Something similar to "Flag as Duplicate" window…

Comment: @meagar no matter if qualifying it as spam was right or not, bluntly stamping it Looks OK was the wrong way to go and audit failure was deserved. At the very least reviewer should have picked editing ot commenting it (if they wanted to do anything else but skip)

Comment: @gnat: I am not complaining about why my audit is failed. I am trying to understand how should I make sure the post is spam with the privileges in hand. I have edited my question much and cast "reopen" vote.

Comment: you needn't make sure, simple as that. You just shouldn't pick Looks OK (prior comments and duplicate explain a bunch of options you had to do it right - skip, edit, comment)

Comment: There is no need for another answer. The guidelines you linked have all the necessary information.

Comment: I found this post that explains guidelines for reviewing: meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/5779732. Other these two related questions. meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286478/5779732 and meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289277/5779732

Comment: That 100% smells like spam or self-promotion--big block of unformatted text ending with a link. When something smells like spam, go look at the context of the entire question. It might help you determine if it is or not, and it also will reveal if the review was an audit.

Comment: With how that answer looks and considering that it was posted to a very old question, it looks suspicious. Going to the question to investigate further is a reasonable thing to do. If you would've done that you would've seen that it was deleted and then you can know that it's an audit. Note that I think that it shouldn't be an audit but you don't need any special privileges to understand what you should do with that review.