# Audit failed with a valid question and comments section seems unrelated

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The link to review is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19693556) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHUqb.png)).

The question seems to be fine, but comment section seems unrelated. Looks like the post had some issue with it, but was edited later and those issues were resolved. Since the question was deleted, there is no way to check this. The way it is currently presented it looks perfectly fine.

I think it should be removed from a list of audit questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't matter. Everyone agrees that the audit selection system / mechanism is flawed.

However, we just can't expect computer programs to work flawlessly. At present, it only knows whether a post is **deleted as** spam (or low-quality). We can't expect it to know whether it actually **is** spam, let alone **why** it is spam (or LQ).

Don't worry. Just move on to reviewing and ignore the consequences of bad audit choices. Post more Meta questions if you're still encountering bad audits.

BSMP's comment sounds very right to me:

> Having the meta record of bad audit encounters is useful should they end up with a review ban. Moderators can't remove individual audits from their record, but they can undo bans.

Comment: Having the meta record of bad audit encounters is useful should they end up with a review ban. Moderators can't remove individual audits from their record, but they can undo bans.

Comment: I once saw the same spam post being presented to me as an audit at least 5 times (that was in VLQ queue), so I assume spam posts are reused. I hoped there is a way to remove this one from audits so that other people wouldn't fail with it. If there is no way to do this, then it is not a big deal, I guess.

Comment: @Ivan Moderators can remove posts from audits by clearing spam flags on the post.

Answer (score -5):

The user [originally posted an answer in their question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50067791/1), but [their answer seems to be misinformed at best](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50067900/1).

The original question for < 10K:

[image]

The answer for < 10K:

[image]

They keep thinking of Java classes in the same analogy as C structs, which is...inappropriate.  It also seems to be the case that they're promoting a library to "get around" this issue when it's not apparent that it's an issue at all.  No sensible Java developer unless they were doing anything with Java Native Interfaces would *care* about structs.

It reads like a spammy attempt at promotion, so it's fine that it's deleted in my mind.  This is a case in which at a glance it's tough to identify, so I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt in the review at least.  (Not that it counts for anything, though.)

Comment: I am more concerned with the fact that the question was edited (inappropriate content was removed) and is now used for audits in its fixed form. Imo it should either be reverted or not used for audits.

Comment: @Ivan They just moved the spam from the question to an answer, they didn't remove the spam.

Comment: @Servy "Answer" section is not visible there. It only shows a question. There is no way to that this happened.

Comment: @Ivan: I highlight the answer in a separate picture.  It is a *proper* answer.  As Servy pointed out...it was just moved to a proper answer box.  Doesn't change the spammy feel of it at all.

Comment: @Ivan It was a question posted for the sole purpose of them posting spam as an answer to it.

Comment: @Makoto There is no answer in the question or at least I am not able to see it (because I have less than 10k rep?). Your screenshots do no match my view of the question.

Comment: You can't see it since you don't have 10K rep.  The screenshots are for your edification so you *can* see them. :)

Comment: @Makoto That is my point. The audit is pointless - it presents perfectly valid question without any "answers" or even links.

Comment: @Ivan:  Do you *know* Java?  Do you know if Java needs to have structs?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I know how Java works and how .Net fixes that issue too. You should read the question the way it is presented in the audit - it _asks_ how this should be used. The answer is "there is no way to do so", but the question is valid. It might be marked as a duplicate if duplicate is there somewhere, but thats it.

Comment: @Ivan That question is there merely to be a platform for spam.  It was deleted as spam, and correctly, because it's spam.  Now you have a valid argument that it was difficult for you to identify why the post was spam from the review queue, and that is an issue, but the post *is* spam.

Comment: @Servy _I am not arguing that it was deleted wrongly_. In fact I specifically said _why it was likely deleted_ in my question. I am arguing that it should not be used for audits. Or its original version should be instead.

Comment: @Ivan You're saying that the question is "valid" and that it's been "fixed" and that all inappropriate content is removed.  If you're aware that it is still spam, and should stay deleted, that's fine, just making sure that that was clear.

Comment: Funny how spam has a knack of surviving on meta.  You'd have to wonder a bit if the spammers have figured out yet how to take advantage of it.

Comment: @HansPassant: They'd have to put effort in to the system to spam on Meta, a barrier which very, very few actual spammers have bothered to cross.

Comment: Funny how we complete fail to communicate over and over again.  I know, it is my fault.  Please consider to not sponsor spammy posts at meta.

Comment: They **know** that Java object are **not** C structs, as directly said in the question. And their question is how to get around it. I think the question is fine.

Comment: Also, [yes, that is a link only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289074/are-answers-with-only-links-to-libraries-okay), but not a spam. I don't know if there is undisclosed affiliation.

Comment: @Servy If you say that the question is a [spam seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed), why is it? (1) it's possible to write a "proper answer" (reimplement the library) and/or (2) it's possible to explain why is it not possible with pure Java.

Comment: @user202729 It's obvious because they included spam in the question, and then when they were called on it they edited it out of the question and posted the same exact spam as an answer (from the same account) to the question right away.  I don't know how it gets any more obvious than that.

Comment: Don't forget that this question is about audit. My point was that the post was edited before it was removed and is now presented to people as an audit, while it has no inappropriate content. Remember that you only see a question, not the answer when going through Triage queue.

Comment: This answer (and ensuing comments) seems to be missing the point of the question: that due to the edits it is impossible for those with <10k rep to "correctly" grade this audit; and so because of this, it should be removed from audit.

Comment: @DewiMorgan:  The fact that the question is *deleted* is probably the biggest red flag you can be given for a review.  If you're reviewing a *deleted* question, 100% of the time it's an audit.  All it's doing is making sure you're paying attention.  A deleted question coming up in review is always a strong indicator that you should be careful here.

Comment: @Makoto - but surely the only way to know that the question is deleted is to try to open the actual question in another tab.  Are you suggesting that every triage reviewer should be doing that for every single question?

Comment: If you should open every single question, the review queue shouldn't be trying to hamstring you with a "partial" view. The question with the latter half edited out is obviously not delete worthy taken at face value

Comment: " No sensible Java developer unless they were doing anything with Java Native Interfaces would care about structs." Then you are wasting a lot of memory. I mean I absolutely love Java, but not having user defined primitives / value types / structs (all names for the same thing) is one of the big weaknesses left in java, and java 10 might even finally get them: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/values.html

Comment: @Polygnome:  Two things.  First, Java  10 is already out and does not contain this.  Second, [this looks like a draft from 2015](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046159) that hasn't made its way out of the gate, and *still* wouldn't change how the JVM actually manages this in terms of memory (which is specified as a generic "non-goal").  It's a solution in search of a few champions, but we're well off-the point of this question by now.

Comment: @Makoto The link you provided explicilty states that project valhalla is still under consideration by Oracle for upcoming Java versions, so... I'm just saying, you shouldn't make such blanket statements about "every sensible Java programmer". That blanket statement is just wrong, value types are highly valuable and sensible, even (and in a way, *especially*) in Java. The overhead introduces by the object header (for runtime type information) and padding is enormous, especially for small structs (3 floats for example).