# Was this answer flag disputed because of an upvote?

Tags: discussion, support, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

I flagged [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133943/how-to-decode-the-subject-in-an-email/6134026#6134026) which is a link-only answer, but it was disputed.

So, my questions here are:

- Is it just because of it having three upvotes?
- Is that answer good?
- What if in the future that link is broken?

And I flagged [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778662/free-or-open-source-microsoft-odbc-jdbc-drivers-to-hive-hadoop/24781142#24781142) which is already accepted. Will that flag also be disputed because it is accepted answer?

Comment: For the first question - The answer you've linked *is not* link-only answer, but rather answer that happen to have a link. I'm quite sure that removing link does not decrease value of the answer - function name that OP was looking for. Sample code could make such answer very good, but adding link *does not* make it bad.

Comment: The canonical answer to your first question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: For the second one, the question is the problem, not the answer.

Comment: for first: You're probably looking for Link. Is this proper answer. in answer there may be some code or aleast describe something for solution.

Comment: @ketan Yes, "You're probably looking for iconv_mime_decode." is perfectly valid, possibly "very low quality" answer. Flagging as VLQ, down-voting, commenting are valid options for such answer. Flagging as "link-only" or "not an answer" are not because valid options as it answers the question and stand by itself if you ignore link and just read text of the post. (Note "link" for purpose of this "link-only" is defined as only "href" attribute of the "A" tag, not *text* inside it)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there is no way to flag as "very low quality" or "link-only" from the answer's page. The options are: "spam", "inappropriate", "not an answer" or "moderator intervention". "Not an answer" is the best fit really...

Comment: @nico: NAA doesn't fit *at all*, though. "Link-only" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @NathanTuggy note that the answer has since (after my comment) been updated. Now I wouldn't consider it link-only as it does have an explanation. Before, it was only a well formatted link, yet only a link. If I need to go offsite to get my answer the answer is not self sufficient and is link only. For instance, I didn't know how to use `iconv_mime_decode` and the answer didn't tell me that, what parameters it accepted, what it returned. Nothing, just the function name and a link. Probably trivial in this case but what if someone answers a question with "you should use preg_match"?

Comment: Now this edited answer is consider as answer. If now in future link broken then also doesn't make any effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm one of the reviewers who [disputed your flag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7888837).

Of the over 2,000 Low Quality Posts that I have reviewed, there are a large number of answers that are so utterly terrible that reviewers have to step in and go so far as to actually delete someone else's post.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133943/how-to-decode-the-subject-in-an-email/6134026#6134026) however, was not one of them.

To directly answer your questions:

> Is it just because of it having three upvotes?

No, not in this case. In some cases, the upvotes can make me hesitant about recommending deletion, depending of the nature of the answer. I skip reviews that I'm not sure about.

> Is that answer good?

While it is not a stellar answer, it **is** an answer, with or without the link. It even relates to the subject in question, which is not always the case.

Since you asked your question, the answer has also been improved by [jakekimds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3161440/jakekimds) to include some code from the linked page.

If you think the answer is bad, you can downvote it. If I had downvoted every bad answer I have come across, I would have lost reputation *in the hundreds*. I only downvote answers that are actually incorrect or otherwise harmful to keep the lost reputation within a few percent of my total.

> What if in the future that link is broken?

The answer addresses the question regardless of the link. Feel free to edit it to fix the broken link, or delete the link if you can't find the new one.

---

Answers that I *do* find delete-worthy are typically one of the following:

- A somewhat related or even totally unrelated **question**, usually in response to a post that is several years old.
- A comment asking for clarification.
- A comment asking if the problem has been solved.
- A comment criticizing another answer.
- "This [link] answers your question" with not even a clue what the answer might be.
- Some random babble with a link to a totally unrelated page (i.e. spam).

Comment: @ketan: Would you believe I forgot to mention link-only answers in my list? Answer updated.

Comment: _"I only downvote answers that are actually incorrect or otherwise harmful to keep the lost reputation within a few percent of my total."_ Don't get too attached to rep. Use it, instead. If a answer's bad, losing rep isn't a reason not to downvote.

Answer (score 26):

Your flag was disputed because it went through the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7888837) and all three people said it Looks Ok. And I agree with them. He explicitly wrote the name of the function to use. It still answers the question without the link.

Comment: I disagree. That is not a self sufficient answer, I still have to go and read the link if I want the solution. He should have put an example of usage and an explanation of what the function does, which are not in the answer.

Comment: @nico So then downvote it and comment. Lack of explanation doesn't make it not an answer or worthy of moderator intervention.

Comment: I just finishing commenting on the answer :)

Comment: I agree, it does not need to be flagged for mods, but it should be flagged as not an answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers

Comment: @nico: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @Deduplicator exactly my point, the 4th of the apple's images is spot on. That answer does not "contain an honest attempt at answering the question". Opinion may vary on this because... well they are opinions.

Comment: @nico: (for explanation, *not* argument:) look at the 2 images above the apples. Look at the [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) why these are (low quality) answers. Now compare that with the Q at hand.. see any similarities? The link-description has info (check), the URL itself has info (check) (and the URL points to the relevant function's description on the official php-site). Here is a [link](http://i.imgsafe.org/0d54b2a.jpg) that holds no information whatsoever.

Comment: @gitaarlab I have seen those and continue to disagree. See my other link for a completely opposite view. If I saw that in the review queue I'd definitely mark it as link only.

Comment: @nico: You're relying on a discussion where the original poster was told he was wrong by a majority of commenters, and chose to argue about it.  That's not a reliable source.

Comment: @ben you mean the question with 32 updates to which the only answer is that of a moderator who agrees with the OP? Anyway luckily I am still entitled to my opinion and I am happy to continue downvoting and flagging those answers.

Comment: @nico: I see no linked question with 32 revisions and only one answer.  You are entitled to your opinion but abusing flags is likely to cause suspension of flagging privileges.  This answer by animuson (also a diamond mod) has gotten 250% as many votes in only four hours as the (wrong) accepted answer on the question you linked.  Remember that acceptance does not mean correct, it means the OP liked it (well of course he liked the answer that said he was right, even if it just isn't true).

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry, it has 2 answers, still it is there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers (it was meant to be upvotes not updates, damn autocorrection...). *[...] it requires you to go off-site to find a solution. We want solutions to be on the site.*

Comment: @nico: you are (somewhat sadly) right that one can find contradicting diamond-posts regardless chronological timeline on meta.SO and meta.SE. However, it appears to me that the diamond*s* who are in the 'castle'-line-of-thought are also official SE Community Managers (according to their profile). That, plus the fact that this 'castle'-guideline gives a nice specified shade of 'gray' to reasonably consistently handle the all-time-favorite question 'Why was my flag declined' on meta, probably makes 'castle' the most popular opinion. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: The best example of my 3rd question you can see in my question. There is second link "another answer" is broken now. There is not found. What if in future that things is happen to that answer. It doesn't helpful to any other people.