# Flag declined on link-only answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, accepted-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged [this link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452457/497418) as "not an answer" which is pointing to

> Check out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910448

It was declined with the following message:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Am I missing something here? [I was under the impression that we should be flagging link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251006/497418).

Comment: Definitely looks link-only to me. Might have something to do with the age and the fact it's accepted, though we won't know 100% until the mod who declined it gives their reasoning.

Comment: And this is why I don't flag link-only answers anymore

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It's not nearly as bad now that mods aren't handling the vast majority of these flags anymore.  It's mostly just accepted answers that get handled by mods.

Comment: I was particularly surprised because my previous flag was for a link only answer, which had slightly more content than this one, and was approved.

Comment: @zzzzBov That likely wasn't sent to a mod.  They tend to be dramatically less likely to delete link only answers than non-moderators reviewing that type of content.

Comment: @Servy - because I'm apparently borderline insane or a masochist, I tried flagging a few again the other day for grins and giggles:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725270/spinners-change-values-in-listview-when-i-scroll-down/31725518#31725518 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177189/display-sqlite-browser-contents/31703917#31703917.  The second is iffy, but I thought for sure the first was valid.  Both were declined by moderators.

Comment: @Servy, i'm not asking for it to be deleted, it's a useful comment.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you flag as NAA, or a custom flag?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, NAA.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It would go to a mod in either case.

Comment: @Servy good to know.  I figure it was NAA based on the rejection text, but I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a "don't use custom flags for thing you can do yourself."

Comment: I checked the KB article because I hoped I could edit the relevant stuff in. Maybe the question is too broad....

Comment: @LittleBobby My flag on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725270/spinners-change-values-in-listview-when-i-scroll-down/31725518#31725518 passed and the answer was deleted. Still awaiting the results of #2.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I think the first might have been due to a misclick, since that should have been deleted and the question was closed as a duplicate properly. The second looks to have been disputed in review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8977635 , and there seems to have been some debate about whether it really was an answer.

Comment: Flagged it.  Hopefully the more people who flag these answers, the more likely they are going to be removed...

Comment: worth keeping in mind that flags on accepted or positive score answers are [guaranteed to go through moderator review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601) even when all 6 LQ reviewers recommended deletion

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but it seems like I remember a a few cases like this where there were multiple flags of the same post. When a mod declined one of the flags it declined them all.

Comment: I might allow it to pass, because _without_ the link, it's a reference to Microsoft's KB. It's undoubtedly a _poor_ answer, but I wouldn't say it's _necessarily_ a 'link only'. *shrug*. Bit borderline really IMO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I umm'd and ahh'd a bit when dealing with the flag in question:

- It's an attempt at providing an answer (albeit link only).
- It's nearly 6 years old.
- It's a link that's less likely to suffer rot than some others.
- It had three upvotes at the time.
- It was accepted.
- It already had a delete vote (presumably recently) so was also available for those with access to the delete queue to handle.

A couple of possible options were (both would remove the "accepted" mark):

- Remove the post completely.
- Convert the post to a comment - which would preserve the link but in a less obvious position.
- Do nothing.

I didn't think anything really needed to be done with the answer (mod wise) so I thought I'd marked the flag as helpful (alas not) and moved on - sorry.

Comment: Sounds fine by me. I get flags wrong about 5% of the time myself, I just needed to check that link only answers were still supposed to be flagged, as I was about to flag another link only answer.

Comment: I think you made the right decision to leave it as is.

Comment: @animuson seem to have overridden you on this  and destroyed an answer that does contain useful information.

Comment: @IanRingrose It looks like the rest of the cleaning brigade has decided to get rid of the question altogether. We had something that looked reasonably useful for anyone looking for "*How to debug remote website [using Visual Studio]?*" . Now it's all gone. <sarcasm>Well done curators!</sarcasm>

Comment: Another Option: Improve the Answer by adding context and/or excerpts from the page linked.

Comment: @Bruno we can reasonably hope for another user to ask the same question, and for better answers this time ;)

Answer (score 18):

You are correct, this is link-only answer, and it does not qualify as a good answer. The answerer does not attempt to add any contextual meaning to the answer, so that future users can benefit from it. Even the link can be dead in future, and then this answer does not have any value.

I am not 100% sure, but the only reason, I feel, why your flag is declined, is because this is an accepted answer by the OP besides the answer's quality OR another reason may be just a wrong button click.

Personally, this happens to me sometimes also. Mostly approved, few declined.

As per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

Comment: I bristle a bit when perfectly valid correct answers to questions are marked as 'not qualifying as a good answer'. If it answers the question, it answers the question. Further, this site might be the only place on the internet where just that question will be asked and answered in such an obvious manner. A fact that is at the heart of the existence of StackExchange.

Comment: @outflak There's nothing wrong with providing a link to an external site, but if you are going to do so, it's wise to quote a relevant portion of the original text if not the entire answer/solution. Otherwise the link could die and the content should be present on this site not some external one.

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft KB links have been around for far longer than any StackOverflow reference, and have been fairly stable all around. The "link-rot" argument is quite poor in this particular case, and anyone capable of reading the URL (OK, I know, they're meant to be opaque in a REST style), could work out which KB number to search for if needed. Just another example of over-the-top curation, as it seems to happen more and more on SO...

Comment: As per the help center, 
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Like most rules, that needs to be taken with a pinch of salt. At the end of the day, NAA flags are there because the main problem is links that disappear. This obsession of assuming SO has to stand purely on its own without the rest of the web around it is unhealthy. A bit of judgement on a case by case basis helps. Here, we had a direct link to the relevant official KB article by Microsoft themselves, with a searchable number in the URL in case we needed to look for cached versions somewhere else for example. That's small useful piece of information is now gone.

Comment: @Bruno:-Yes, Agreed on this, its Microsoft KB link, but sometimes in future this link may be changed or as a normal user, before open to any link, I like to know what that link going to give me. It is also possible that many new users can came and just put lots of MSDN links to different questions, then its hard to figure out which one is helpful

Comment: OT: can you please review [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326100/encouraging-editors-not-familiar-with-the-topic-to-skip-not-reject)? I've edited to and would like to ask for another look in order to consider reopening it.

Answer (score -13):

I don't see this as a link-*only* answer. It is saying read [kb/910448](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910448) for an explanation for how to set up remote debugging.

The answer has now been deleted (rather than converted into a comment) by a different mod. The result of this action is that a question that has gotten 2356 views no longer has a useful answer.

**How is that helping all the people that find the** ***question*** **via Google?**

Comment: Ian.... if you feel strongly enough about the answer there is nothing stopping you from getting in there and editing it into shape, quoting some of the target page and generally fleshing it out. A link and nothing else is a garbage answer - no matter what it points to.

Comment: I see that you have now left a comment on the question that contains the [same link to kb/910448](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910448) that was included in the now-deleted answer. That will certainly prove helpful to those who encounter this question in the future.

Comment: Are you sure that *Microsoft Knowledge Base articles* are being left out of Google indexing? Really?

Comment: You don't see it as a "link _only_" answer? I suppose in a pedantic way you're right in that the answer also includes the text "Check out:". In the true spirit of why link-only answers are not appropriate though, if the link becomes bad (for any reason, even MS just shifting their URL plan a little), the answer cannot stand alone. My opinion is that links are fine for additional detail, but if following the link is _required_ in order to get value from the answer, the answer is link-only.

Comment: @mah Technically, with the MSFT KB, the link still contained the KB number, so even if the URL changed, the KB number itself would still be there which would allow the content to still be found. Having said that, I completely agree that the relevant part should have been quoted if at all reasonable.

Comment: Ian, why do you say an MSFT KB article isn't likely to show up in a Google search? That seems like a very counter-intuitive claim.

Comment: Ian, you changed my mind on this, because you are right, it is a poor answer, but without the link it does still contain all the same information.