# Why was this flag on a link-only answer declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648709/9374673) as "Not an Answer" as it contains only the following content:

> > My question is, will the for loop have it's own execution context?
>
> Nope.
>
> [Context and variable scope in ES6 loops and forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685290/context-and-variable-scope-in-es6-loops-and-foreach)

Here's the declined message I received:

[image: flag declined by moderator who reviewed but found no supporting evidence]

I've reviewed nearly 4,000 low quality posts, among them probably hundreds of link-only answers. What makes this answer different? Is it the "Nope."? If the question can be answered with a link to another Stack Overflow post, shouldn't this person have flagged/voted to close as a duplicate?

I read up on a few older questions on Meta such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300786/9374673) which seem to deal with similar problems. I can understand the mitigating circumstances described in that particular example, but don't see how they apply here.

Could someone explain why this was declined, so that I can avoid flagging similar answers in the future?

Comment: It is an answer, because if [you remove the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/332043), it says the answer. No. That's simply the answer in this context. Sure, it's not the best answer and it should've included details directly, but the answer is basically a downvotable one, not a deletable one.

Comment: It contains one bit of data: "Nope" in response to the question. That's not zero, I guess.

Comment: @Zoe fair enough, thanks for linking me to Shog's post again. I forgot that was the canonical on this topic. While I disagree with that stance and agree with the top-upvoted answer on that question, it does make sense why someone would decline that particular flag. Thanks for taking the time to explain.